# Lorentz boost matrix for an arbitrary direction in terms of rapidity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

We have derived the Lorentz boost matrix for a boost in the x-direction in class, in terms of rapidity which from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) is:

Assume boost is along a direction $\hat{n}=n_x \hat{i}+n_y \hat{j}+n_z \hat{k}$,

[image]

How do I generalise this to a boost in any arbitrary direction, and what is the result? Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Just conjugate with rotation matrices.

Comment: I have solved this problem myself, so maybe I should write an answer. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yeah you definitely should.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub, I posted an answer down which works, but I am interested in your method with the rotation matrices. Would you give more info on that?

Comment: Want to comment that it is discussed in textbooks. See Tjiang and Sutanto "Comment on 'Lorentz transformations with arbitrary line of motion'" https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/28/3/N02 ; They cited textbooks Jackson "Classical Electrodynamics" 3rd, page 525, Goldstein "Classical Mechanics" 3rd, page 281.

Answer (score 6):

This answer describes how to transform event coordinates in $S$ to $S'$ coordinates when $S'$ is moving with general velocity $\vec{v}$ in $S$ frame.

Using [The General Lorentz Transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWABqiuIX6c) YouTube video, it can be done in the following way:

Let $\vec{r}=\vec{r}(ct, x, y, z)$ in $S$, and this same event in $S'$ be $\vec{r}'=\vec{r}'(ct', x', y', z')$. $S'$ is moving away from $S$ with velocity $\vec{v}$.

---

### Spatial coordinates

Ignoring the $ct$ dependence of $r$ and $r'$ for now, write $\vec{r}$ as a sum of two vectors, one parallel with $\vec{v}$, one perpendicular to it.

$\vec{r}=\vec{r}_{\parallel}+\vec{r}_{\perp}$.

Since only the parallel component to $\vec{v}$ is not Lorentz invariant, we can write:

$$\vec{r}'=\vec{r}_{\perp}+\gamma(\vec{r}_{\parallel}-\vec{v}t)$$

Rewrite, using $\vec{r}_{\perp}=\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{\parallel}$:

$$\vec{r}'=\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{\parallel}+\gamma(\vec{r}_{\parallel}-\vec{v}t)$$

$$\vec{r}'=\vec{r}+(\gamma-1)\vec{r}_{\parallel}-\gamma\vec{v}t$$

Writing $\vec{r}_{\parallel}$ as:

$$\vec{r}_{\parallel} = \vec{r}\cdot{\hat{\vec{v}}}\hat{\vec{v}}=\frac{\vec{r}\cdot{\vec{v}}\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|^2}$$

we have:

$$\vec{r}'=-\gamma\vec{v}t+\vec{r}+(\gamma-1)\frac{\vec{r}\cdot{\vec{v}}\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|^2}$$

Expand terms of $\vec{r}'$:

$$x'=-\gamma v_x t + x + (\gamma -1)\frac{(xv_x)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_x + (\gamma -1)\frac{(yv_y)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_x + (\gamma -1)\frac{(zv_z)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_x$$

$$y'=-\gamma v_y t + y + (\gamma -1)\frac{(xv_x)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_y + (\gamma -1)\frac{(yv_y)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_y + (\gamma -1)\frac{(zv_z)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_y$$

$$z'=-\gamma v_z t + z + (\gamma -1)\frac{(xv_x)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_z + (\gamma -1)\frac{(yv_y)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_z + (\gamma -1)\frac{(zv_z)}{|\vec{v}|^2}v_z$$

---

### Time dependence

In standard configuration, the $ct$ dependence transforms as:

$$ct'=\gamma\left(ct-\frac{vx}{c}\right)$$

Where $vx$ is: the component ($x$) of whatever event we are Lorentz transforming in the direction of the movement of the primed frame ($S'$), times the speed ($v$)of the movement of $S'$. Now $S'$ is not moving along the positive $x$ direction anymore, so replace $vx$ with $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{r}$: this is the component of $\vec{r}$ in the direction of $S'$-movement unit-vector $\hat{\vec{v}}$ times the speed $v$. So we have:

$$ct'=\gamma\left(ct-\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{r}}{c}\right)=\gamma ct - \gamma \frac{xv_x}{c} -\gamma \frac{yv_y}{c} - \gamma \frac{zv_z}{c}$$

---

### Matrix form

Put the equations above to matrix form, using notation: $\vec{\beta}=\frac{\vec{v}}{c}$ and $\beta=|\vec{\beta}|$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
           ct' \\
           x' \\
           y' \\
           z'
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \gamma & -\gamma\beta_x & -\gamma\beta_y & -\gamma\beta_z\\
    -\gamma\beta_x & 1+(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x^2}{\beta^2} & (\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_y \beta_x}{\beta^2} & (\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_z \beta_x}{\beta^2} \\
    -\gamma\beta_y & (\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x \beta_y}{\beta^2} & 1+(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_y^2}{\beta^2} & (\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_z \beta_y}{\beta^2} \\
    -\gamma\beta_z & (\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x \beta_z}{\beta^2} & (\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_y \beta_z}{\beta^2} & 1+(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_z^2}{\beta^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
           ct \\
           x \\
           y \\
           z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which is also the matrix given in [Thomas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/153306/thomas-fritsch)' [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56085/212053), so we are done.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Wikipedia - Lorentz transformation - Proper transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Proper_transformations)?

I think that is almost what you need:
$$\begin{bmatrix} ct' \\ x' \\ y' \\ z' \\ \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
 \gamma &-\gamma \beta_x &-\gamma \beta_y &-\gamma \beta_z \\ 
-\gamma \beta_x&1+(\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_x^2}{\beta^2}&  (\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_x \beta_y}{\beta^2}&  (\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_x \beta_z}{\beta^2} \\ 
-\gamma \beta_y&  (\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_y \beta_x}{\beta^2}&1+(\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_y^2}  {\beta^2}&  (\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_y \beta_z}{\beta^2} \\ 
-\gamma \beta_z&  (\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_z \beta_x}{\beta^2}&(\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_z \beta_y}{\beta^2}&1+(\gamma-1)\dfrac{\beta_z^2}  {\beta^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} ct \\ x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need, but my question is how do you get is, from the lorentz boost matrices along x-, y- and z- directions?

Comment: @user7757 Why do you want to do that? That sounds difficult, since two different Lorentz boosts in different directions applied one after another don’t generally result in another Lorentz boost, but will because of [holonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) also result in a spatial rotation (in other words, it will result in a Lorentz transformation that is not strictly a boost any more).

Comment: @user7757 If you’re wondering why, the reason you get holonomy is because a Lorentz boost of a four-velocity is analogous to a translation of a point in three-dimensional [hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space), $\textbf{H}^3$, which is curved.

Answer (score -4):

You act with an arbitrary rotation on the boost in one direction.

Comment: Could you elaborate by editing your answer?