# What is wrong with this derivation of the Special Relativity Doppler Shift formula?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

I tried to use the Lorentz coordinate transformation between two inertial frames to generate the Doppler Shift formula, but I ended up with $\lambda$ over $\lambda'$ upside-down. I must have a fundamental error but I can't find it. (Frobenius has published a different, correct, proof of this equation in this forum, but it would help me to understand why mine fails. I suspect it is something fundamental.)

Suppose inertial frame K' having center O' is moving with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ with respect to inertial frame K having center O. The 3+1 Lorentz coordinate transformation $x^{\mu'} = \Lambda_\nu^{\mu'} x^\nu$ can be considered to represent the spatial origin O' moving with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ and coinciding with O at *t* = *t'* = 0, where $\Lambda_\nu^{\mu'} = \gamma \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -\frac{\mathbf{v}}{c} \\ -\frac{\mathbf{v}}{c} & I \\\end{array}\right)$. (Boldface $\mathbf{v}$ represents velocity whereas I use unbolded v to represent the speed of  $\mathbf{v}$.) This equation is a straight-forward generalization of the 1+1 Lorentz formula. I have not seen this formula elsewhere. I guessed it, and then proved it by imitating the 1+1 proof.

Suppose a photon is launched with a frame K velocity $\mathbf{w}$ = c $\mathbf{n}$ from a point P that is a distance of one wavelength $\lambda$ from O, where $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit vector in the direction of photon flight (LHS Figure; $x^3$ axis not shown to keep figure easy-to-read). Suppose, further, that the photon arrives at point O at *t* = 0 (when O’ also arrives at O).
[image]

We will apply the Lorentz coordinate transformation to the point $x^\mu$ whose time coordinate is the time of photon launch and whose space coordinate is P. Let $t_P$ be the photon flight time from P to O, so that $\lambda$ = *c* $t_P$, and the 4-vector for the launch event is $x^\mu$ = ($x^0$, ***x***) = (-*c* $t_P$, -$\lambda$ ***n***) = (-$\lambda$, -$\lambda$ ***n***).

To find the K' frame coordinate $x^{\mu'}$ (RHS Figure), note that the photon still travels one wavelength $\lambda$' from P to O, but the target, O, is moving with velocity -**v**. So, we must determine the space coordinates of O at photon arrival. Because the photon arrives at O at *t* = *t*' = 0, then it arrives at O when O coincides with O' as shown.

From this, using the RHS figure, we see that the time coordinate (i.e., launch time) for $x^{\mu'}$ is -$t_P^{'}$, where $t_P^{'}$ is the frame K' photon flight time. Then $\lambda$' = *c* $t_P^{'}$ and $x^{\mu'}$ = (-*c* $t_P^{'}$, ***x***') = (-$\lambda$', ***x***'). So, the first of the two Lorentz coordinate equations yields

$-\lambda' = x^{0'} = \gamma\;[ x^0-\frac{\mathbf{v}}{c}\bullet\mathbf{x}\,] = \gamma\;[ -\lambda\,-\frac{\mathbf{v}}{c}\bullet(-\lambda\,\mathbf{n})\,] = -\gamma\lambda\,(\,1-\frac{\mathbf{v}\bullet\mathbf{w}}{c^2}).$

This is equivalent to $$\frac{\lambda'}{\lambda}=\gamma\,(1-\frac{\mathbf{v}\bullet\mathbf{w}}{c^2}),$$ upside down of the correct answer.

Comment: That formula for $\Lambda$ doesn't look right to me. I derive the general 3+1 boost [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/649049/107092); [Wikipedia has a reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lorentz_transformation&oldid=1090093193#Proper_transformations). Also, $\Lambda$ is symmetric, but you should still get into the habit of writing ${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu,$ not $\Lambda^\mu_\nu.$ Also also, I would not imagine coordinate systems in SR with moving origins. The origin should be a single *event* (including $t$), and the frame is identified by the origin plus 4 axes.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I observe that our formulas for $\Lambda$ are identical if $\mathbf{x}$ = $\mathbf{v}t$. So, I will check where I might have used that assumption in my derivation of $\Lambda$. I also observe that $\mathbf{x}$ = $\mathbf{v}t$ is true in frame K for the point O', but since I applied my $\Lambda$ to the point P, that was a mistake. Also, thank you for your Lie approach. I am inclined to try to correct my simpler approach rather than to fill in the many details you purposely omitted, but I appreciate seeing both the correct formula for $\Lambda$ and your proof.